# Usage of the word "meet"

Tags: idioms, verbs

I saw some expression like the following : "I met a design problem in .... ", is it a right usage of the word "meet". It just sounds odd to me. I would rather use  "ran into" or "encountered" instead. Any advice ?

Answer (score 6):

*Met a problem* is a right usage of *meet*:

> **[Meet](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/meet):**
>   **1.** to come upon; come into the presence of; encounter: *I would meet him on the street at unexpected moments.*

That said, *encountered a problem* or *ran into a problem* would be more common.  *Meet* simply sounds more reciprocal, where the other two choices only connote activity on your part.  [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=met%20a%20problem,encountered%20a%20problem,ran%20into%20a%20problem&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shows the following:

[image]

Comment: +1 because nothing you say is untrue. Until you pointed it out I never consciously registered the fact that *meeting* is normally reciprocal. But don't forget that *encounter* and *run into* are also used with exactly the same implied reciprocity when the "object" of the verb is another person.

Comment: Emphatic +1 for the use of ngrams. Good answer!

Comment: Nice answer. Not only did I meet a problem, but the problem met me.

Answer (score 2):

It is certainly correct to use *[meet a problem](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/meet_6)* to mean to experience a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

> I met a problem

sounds a little odd but is perfectly fine. It's metaphorical, an example of personification.

So now you have three choices with different stylistic connotations:
- 'met' for metaphorical
- 'encountered' is more formal
- 'ran in to' is informal (and slightly metaphorical, you problem didn't make physical contact)

Answer (score 0):

"I *met* a design problem in .... ":
substituting
"*ran into*" or "*encountered*"
does not make a difference, at least to me, in the meaning conveyed or in sentence construction.

Agreed, the use of *meet* in such a context may be relatively rare, making it appear out of place. It is not due to a grammatical error. In that sense, it is certainly *odd*, though not *wrong*.